# How to use group by in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I'm taking data from the Database for loading into qlikview.
I have to create a chart with the percentage of inflow tickets group by SR(Column name). How do ido that? The expression for numerator and denominator looks the same to me. Is there a way to group by?

Comment: Can you please provide some data example and what is your expression look like?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you're trying to build something that looks like this

[image: Relative Percentage]

To add the relative % all you have to do is copy and paste the expression for the sum of calls and then add the relative tick to the 2nd expression

Notice that the expressions are exactly the same except for the relative tick. This tells QlikView to divide the dimensional answer by the dimensionless total.

[image: Count Expression]
[image]